# Multiplicar valores de índices pares de uma string em C

Tags: c, string, char

A questão que eu preciso resolver é a seguinte: A pessoa informa um numero, eu preciso multiplicar por 2 todos os números que estiverem no "índice" par, o problema é que o índice começa em 1 pela direita. Por exemplo, o número 49927398716 seria reescrito como 4(18)9(4)7(6)9(16)7(2)6.

Meu raciocínio foi: inverter o número para que assim eu possa multiplicar os indices [i] + 1 * 2. Eu consegui inverter, entretanto, quando eu multiplico os números, o programa me retorna letras invés de números.

Código:

```
void checkfinal(char num[]){    
    int tamanho = strlen(num);
    char aux[50];   
    int i, j=0;

    for(i= tamanho-1;i>=0;i--){
        aux[j]=num[i];
        j++;
    }

    aux[j]=0;

    for( j = 1; j <= tamanho; j++)
    {

       if(j%2==0){
           aux[j-1] = aux[j-1] * 2;
       }
    }

    printf("%s", aux);
}
```

Comment: O problema está bem mal definido então dá pra interpretar ele de várias formas e a pergunta não tem uma dúvida específica. Por isso acho que tem vários erros no algoritmo. e provavelmente a solução nem deveria ser essa.

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário inverter, basta determinar se o total de algarismos é par ou ímpar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char num[1024], result[2048]="", aux[3];
    int i, incr;
    printf("Informe o número: ");
    gets(num); /* seria melhor fgets */
    incr = (strlen(num) % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(num); i++) {
        sprintf(aux, "%d", (i%2 == incr) ? num[i]-'0': (num[i]-'0') * 2);
        strcat(result, aux);
    }
    printf("Original: %s\nModificado: %s", num, result);
    return 0;
}
```